# Actual MS Excel formula for vdb()

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to rewrite a vdb() function in Python, I can't find the actual math formula on the internet. Here is the description for the function.

> VDB function
>
> This article describes the formula syntax and usage of the VDB
>   function in Microsoft Excel.
>
> Description    Returns the depreciation of an asset for any period you
>   specify, including partial periods, using the double-declining balance
>   method or some other method you specify. VDB stands for variable
>   declining balance.
>
> Syntax
>
> VDB(cost, salvage, life, start_period, end_period, [factor],
>   [no_switch])
>
> The VDB function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> Cost    Required. The initial cost of the asset.
>
> Salvage    Required. The value at the end of the depreciation
>   (sometimes called the salvage value of the asset). This value can be
>   0.
>
> Life    Required. The number of periods over which the asset is
>   depreciated (sometimes called the useful life of the asset).
>
> Start_period    Required. The starting period for which you want to
>   calculate the depreciation. Start_period must use the same units as
>   life.
>
> End_period    Required. The ending period for which you want to
>   calculate the depreciation. End_period must use the same units as
>   life.
>
> Factor    Optional. The rate at which the balance declines. If factor
>   is omitted, it is assumed to be 2 (the double-declining balance
>   method). Change factor if you do not want to use the double-declining
>   balance method. For a description of the double-declining balance
>   method, see DDB.
>
> No_switch    Optional. A logical value specifying whether to switch to
>   straight-line depreciation when depreciation is greater than the
>   declining balance calculation.    If no_switch is TRUE, Microsoft
>   Excel does not switch to straight-line depreciation even when the
>   depreciation is greater than the declining balance calculation. If
>   no_switch is FALSE or omitted, Excel switches to straight-line
>   depreciation when depreciation is greater than the declining balance
>   calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The Variable Declining Balance (vdb) method is a combined method of the Declining Balance Depreciation method and the Straight Line Depreciation method, provided `no_switch` is FALSE or omitted. Otherwise, the standard depreciation method is used even when depreciation is greater than the declining balance calculation. The following assumes `no_switch` is FALSE or omitted.

> The depreciation calculation starts with the declining method.  At the
>   period in the life of the asset where the depreciation calculated by
>   the straight line method on the remaining depreciable amount will be
>   greater than the amount calculated by the declining method, you switch
>   to the straight line method for the remainder of the life of the
>   asset.

The formulas are:

> Declining Balance:
>
> 1. Straight-Line Depreciation Percent = 100% / Useful Life
> 2. Depreciation Rate = Depreciation Factor x Straight-Line Depreciation Percent
> 3. Depreciation for a Period = Depreciation Rate x Book Value at Beginning of the Period
>
> Switching to Straight Line Method:
>
> 1. Depreciation in Any Remaining Period = ((Cost - Accumulated Depreciation) / Remaining Life)

Source & online calculator [here](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/financial/depreciation-variable-declining-balance.php), where you can find links to information about the Declining Balance Depreciation method and the Straight Line Depreciation method as well.

Answer (score 0):

The VDB function is discussed here:
http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Vdb-Function.html

It's default is the Double Declining-Balance Method which can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depreciation#Doubling_Declining_balance_method